# Primer/library loop function only executes once

Tags: javascript, html, loops, foreach

I went through all the 'loop fires only once' questions, but couldn't find the solution for my problem.

I'm working on a project that needs a lot of loop functions, with elements as subjects. I thought I'd make a library function (I think 'primer function' is a better term) that I can call later with every time just one line of code. So I tried, but it's not behaving as I expected, because it only fires once. This is my experimental code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <script>
        var forAll = function(elems) {
            for (var i=0, n=elems.length; i<n; i++) {
                console.log('The elems[i] == ' + elems[i]);
                return elems[i];
            }
        }
        var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
        forAll(demos).style.color = 'red';
        console.log('The forAll(demos) ==' + forAll(demos));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That the primer function only fires once can be seen from the result and from the console. What am I doing wrong? I totally taught myself Javascript, so please go easy on me if I'm missing basic stuff.

Add: IE11 is a much used browser in this case, so `forEach` is not an option.

Comment: What exactly do you expect that function to do? The way you're calling it, it seems that it's expected to return a single DOM element reference because you dereference the "style" property on the returned value. In that case, the loop doesn't really make sense anyway, as written. It might make sense if the intention is to somehow *filter* the list of elements to find one in particular.

Comment: I expect the function to turn all span texts red.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop in this function will iterate only once :

```
var forAll = function(elems) {
        for (var i=0, n=elems.length; i<n; i++) {
            console.log('The elems[i] == ' + elems[i]);
            return elems[i];
        }
    }
```

The return stops the for loop and returns the execution of the function.

**Edit:** Here is a code snippet that might do what you expect as suggested by @AndroidNoobie

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <script>
        var forAll = function(elems) {
            for (var i=0, n=elems.length; i<n; i++) {
                elems[i].style.color = 'red';
            }
            
            return elems;
        }
        var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');           
        console.log('The forAll(demos) ==' + forAll(demos));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may be right, but `console.log('The elems[i] == ' + elems[i]);` also gives just the first span.

Comment: @FrankConijn a `return` statement most definitely will exit its containing function immediately. That's the whole point of `return`.

Comment: @FrankConijn It's giving all 4 spans. Drop the `return` statement and replace it with `elems[i].style.color = 'red';` and you should see all four spans turn red.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie -- That throws an error: "'elems' is not defined'.

Comment: @FrankConijn No it doesn't — the code snippet works fine. Click the blue "Run" button and see.

Comment: @Pointy -- I now see what you mean, but with the edit the code has moved `elems[i].style.color = 'red';` to the `forAll` function. That's not what a library/primer function is about.

Comment: @FrankConijn Your question is why the loop only iterates once. It only iterates once beause of your `return` statement. You then told @Pointy that you expect the function to turn all spans red. The function now does that. I've never heard of the term "primer function". You might want to edit your question (or create another) to clarify what you're really asking about.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie -- How about the term library function then?

Comment: @FrankConijn Setting a "style" property like that works when you have a reference to a *single* DOM element. If you want to make something that allows an update to a *list* of elements, you'd have to wrap the list with some sort of object like jQuery does.

Comment: @Pointy -- OK, but how does jQuery do that? I don't wanna have to include the whole jQuery library.

Comment: @FrankConijn well it's a simple basic idea but jQuery was a significant bit of work when it was first released. It's a big topic and there are lots of architectural decisions to be made.

Answer (score 2):

I think your actual question is "How can I implement `forEach`-like behavior in browsers that don't support `forEach`?"

In that case, you can do something like this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `forEach` on your array (although, generally speaking, it's not a great idea to modify the prototypes of built-in objects like arrays).

But your asked question (why the loop only iterates once) has already been answered by @facundo and @Pointy.

**Edit:** Added code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <script>
    
        if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
          Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
              for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
                  fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
              }
          }
        }
        var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
        demos.forEach(function(item){
            item.style.color = 'red';
        })
        console.log('The forAll(demos) ==' + demos);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but how would the whole code look like, then? Because isn't it so that the arrow function that is needed in a `forEach` function is not supported by IE either?

Comment: @FrankConijn code block would look like this https://jsfiddle.net/74jubnc9/

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort you're putting into it. But unfortunately, the integral code throws an error in IE11: "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'."

Comment: @FrankConijn you were right. I've already requested to edit the code snippet. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/74jubnc9/12/) is the way it should be to invoke the right forEach.  https://jsfiddle.net/74jubnc9/12/

Comment: @facundo -- Bingo! That's brilliant. I knew that IE could work with `forEach` only within an `array`, but I would not have come up with that code anytime soon. And certainly not bug-free. Thanks a lot! I'll leave it up to you and AndroidNoobie which answer is going to contain that code in full, and I'll tick that as the accepted answer. Plus, I'll up the other one then, because you both helped out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It eventually appeared very easy to make Internet Explorer (IE) support `forEach` with NodeLists. By means of a tiny polyfill, as found on http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach/:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <script>
        // Polyfill to make IE9+ support forEach w/ NodeLists:
        (function () {
            if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "function")
                return false;
            else 
                NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        })();

        // Works with NodeLists (i.e. HTMLcollections):
        var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
        demos.forEach(function(item) {
                item.style.color = 'red';
        })

        // As well as with Arrays:
        var gurkins = ['gur1', 'gur2', 'gur3'];
        gurkins.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested in IE11, and according to its emulate function, it works in 10 and 9, too (not 8).

Thanks for you time and effort, facundo and AndroidNoobie, but you will probably understand that this is the best solution.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Just keep in mind, your actual question asked why the loop only executed once. That was answered by @facundo. I only mention this because if other users search for a similar question in the future, they may not understand why the chosen answer has to do with the `forEach` function. :-) It might be better to submit an edit to @facundo's answer to add your solution, that way both cases are covered. But thanks for the kudos and I'm very glad you got it working!